# AWS Golang SDK fails to copy object when the key contains arabic characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Using [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go), I have been able to sucessfully copy the objects in my s3 bucket when the key contains normal alphanumeric and few special characters like (-,_). But when a key contains an arabic character, the golang aws-sdk throws an error.

```
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
    status code: 404, request id: 438DC6xxxxxx, host id: Xp+xxxxxxxxxx
```

The key in the bucket looks like this:

`public/10009/img__١٣٤١١١-1600x1200.jpg`

The code is pretty straigh-forward as well:

```golang
func copyObject(existingKey, key string, svc *s3.S3) {
    copyObjectInput := &s3.CopyObjectInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String("dummy-bucket"),
        CopySource: aws.String(existingKey),
        Key:        aws.String(key),
    }

    result, err := svc.CopyObject(copyObjectInput)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Copy failed due to: ", err) // logs the above error here
    }

    spew.Dump(result)
}
```

I am also printing out the key, just in case:
`dummy-bucket/public/10009/img__١٣٤١١١-1600x1200.jpg`

I was also able to successfully downloaded the image using the `aws-sdk-go`, with the same key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, CopySource must be URL-encoded.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#CopyObjectInput

```
// The name of the source bucket and key name of the source object, separated
// by a slash (/). Must be URL-encoded.
//
// CopySource is a required field
CopySource *string `location:"header" locationName:"x-amz-copy-source" type:"string" required:"true"`
```

Try this,

```
import "net/url"

func copyObject(existingKey, key string, svc *s3.S3) {

    // existingKey is source bucket and key name separated by "/"
    e := url.QueryEscape(existingKey)

    copyObjectInput := &s3.CopyObjectInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String("dummy-bucket"),
        CopySource: aws.String(e),
        Key:        aws.String(key),
    }

    result, err := svc.CopyObject(copyObjectInput)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Copy failed due to: ", err) // logs the above error here
    }

    spew.Dump(result)
}
```